Pan orthographic non-axis-aligned camera
I'm trying to create a panning control for a camera in bevy, but I can't seem to get the panning logic right when the camera is rotated. It works fine if the camera transform is directly facing the XY plane. This works with any axis as the "up" direction:
Transform::from_xyz(0., 0., 1.).looking_at(Vec3::ZERO, Vec3::X)

But, it doesn't move correctly when the camera isn't aligned to the plane, like so:
Transform::from_xyz(1., -2., 2.).looking_at(Vec3::ZERO, Vec3::Z)

I want the camera to pan over the XY plane at a fixed Z height.
How can I convert this 2D implementation to a proper 3D implementation?
Here's the pseudocode for my current logic:
Vec2 delta_mouse = get_mouse_movement_since_last_frame();
Angle camera_rotation = camera.get_rotation_axis_and_angle().angle;
Vec2 rotation_mat = { x: cos(camera_rotation), y: sin(camera_rotation) };
Vec2 rotated_delta_mouse = {
    x: delta_mouse.x * rotation_mat.x - delta_mouse.y * rotation_mat.y,
    y: delta_mouse.y * rotation_mat.x + delta_mouse.x * rotation_mat.y
};
camera.translation += rotated_delta_mouse;


The code looking_at(Vec3::ZERO rotates the camera axis to always face (0,0,0).
Remove the camera_rotation
Adjust both camera.translation and a new lookat_target that replaces Vec3::ZERO with delta_mouse
Vec2 delta_mouse = get_mouse_movement_since_last_frame();

lookat_target += delta_mouse; // defined globally

camera.translation += delta_mouse;

Then:
Transform::from_xyz(x, y,1.).looking_at(lookat_target, Vec3::Z)
